# calculate total overall audio play time audio service flutter for analytic purpose

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics, mixpanel, audio-service

calculate overall audio played in session using audio_service plugin flutter

```
void _listenToPlaybackState() {
        _audioHandler.playbackState.listen(
                (playbackState) {
                    final isPlaying = playbackState.playing;
                    // if (isPlaying) {
                    //   shouldShowMiniPlayerNotfier.value = true;
                    //   if (_currentPlayingEpisode.isNegative == false) {
                    //     var episodeId = _currentPlayingEpisode;
                    //     log('hitting play api for episodeId: $episodeId ::: $_currentPlayingEpisode');
                    //     _currentPlayingEpisode = -1;
                    //     podcastsController.updatePlayCountOfEpisodeById(episodeId);
                    //   }
                    // }
                    final processingState = playbackState.processingState;
                    if (processingState == AudioProcessingState.loading ||
                        processingState == AudioProcessingState.buffering) {
                        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.loading;
                    } else if (!isPlaying) {
                        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.paused;
                        log("Audio Paused ${currentMediaItemIdNotifier.value}");
                    } else if (processingState != AudioProcessingState.completed) {
                        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.playing;
                        `       // MixpanelManager.timeEvent(MixPanel.audioPlayingTimeSpent);
          log("Audio Play ${currentMediaItemIdNotifier.value}");
        } else if (processingState == AudioProcessingState.idle) {
          playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.stopped;
          log("Audio Stopped ${currentMediaItemIdNotifier.value}");
        } else {
          _audioHandler.seek(Duration.zero);
          _audioHandler.pause();
        }
      },
    );
}
```

I have posted a example for login event when user tries to play audio from notification panel or button. please help setting up analytics events